# How to Edit a database row in C# and ASP.NET Core 6.0 MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0

I'm new at MVC. Last project I used list and I am replacing them with a database.

Delete went well, but updating not soo well.

I looked online but hadn't had much luck. I took a few lines that I had, basically if all goes well I go to index if the changes weren't made the user would stay on index...

I stayed on index.

Nothing changed in database of course...

I don't know if it´s related but maybe it's on conflict to pass the ID value to the database that is a primary key, that would be weird since I only allow the user to change Name, Last Name and Birth date

Model class:

```
public partial class Person
{
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public string FirstName { get; set; } = null!;
       public string LastName { get; set; } = null!;
       public DateTime Birth { get; set; }
       public int Roles { get; set; }

       public virtual ICollection<ClassDetail> ClassDetails { get; set; } = new List<ClassDetail>();
       public virtual Role RolesNavigation { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

View:

```
@model WebApplication2.School_dbModels.Person

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit";
}

<h1>Edit</h1>

<h4>Person</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Edit">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="FirstName" class="control-label">First Name</label>
                <input asp-for="FirstName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="LastName" class="control-label">Last Name</label>
                <input asp-for="LastName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Birth" class="control-label">Birthday</label>
                <input asp-for="Birth" class="form-control"/>
                <span asp-validation-for="Birth" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Controller edit action method:

```
// GET: Students/Edit/5
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    Person studentToEdit = db.People.Find(id);

    return View(studentToEdit);
}

// POST: Students/Edit/5
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(Person studentToEdit)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Person student = db.People.Where(s => s.Id == studentToEdit.Id).First();
        student.FirstName = studentToEdit.FirstName;
        student.LastName = studentToEdit.LastName;
        student.Birth = studentToEdit.Birth;

        db.Entry(student).State = EntityState.Modified;

        db.SaveChanges();

        // Refresh the index page with updated data
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(studentToEdit);
}
```

Comment: You can set a breakpoint at `if (ModelState.IsValid)` to see if any error . What's the result of ModelState.IsValid ?

Comment: If (ModelState.IsValid) should return to index, even if nothing is changed in the table. Since the ModelState.IsValid is false, it stays on the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your problem may be caused by invalid  Roles,ClassDetails ,RolesNavigation ,
you can try to add `?` manully to like:

```
public int? Roles { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<ClassDetail> ? ClassDetails { get; set; } = new List<ClassDetail>();
  
public virtual Role? RolesNavigation { get; set; } = null!;
```

**or:** you can remove `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` from your project file (double-click the project name or right-click the project to choose Edit Project File). You can read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#build-the-app) to know more.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the state will mark the entity as dirty and try to update all properties. Attach can be the solution as you are intended to update specific properties.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]   
public ActionResult Edit(Person studentToEdit)
{
 if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    Person student = db.People.Where(s => s.Id == studentToEdit.Id).First();
    db.Attach(student);
    student.FirstName = studentToEdit.FirstName;
    student.LastName = studentToEdit.LastName;
    student.Birth = studentToEdit.Birth;       

    db.SaveChanges();

    // Refresh the index page with updated data
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
  }
  return View(studentToEdit);
}
```

Comment: `Attach` is not needed (unless there is something else going on that is not shown in the OP's code).

Comment: As Qing Guo mentioned, my problem was caused by invalid Roles,ClassDetails,RolesNavigation; however, I took what you posted into consideration and removed that line. Thank you!!